# Is it possible to have an ActiveRecord-backed Utility class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a "utility" class:

```
class Hostname
 attr_reader :domain

 def initialize(hostname)
  @domain = Foo.bar(hostname)
 end
end
```

Where I do things like:

```
$ Hostname.new('www.abc.com').domain 
> 'abc.com'
```

I want this class to be ActiveRecord-backed so I can save Hostname to my DB.

I've read lots of posts against overriding ActiveRecord's initialize method. Do I need to have a separate class/namespace for the utility class?

I want to avoid the following:

```
$ Hostname.new(:hostname => 'www.abc.com').domain
> 'abc.com'
```

What's the "rails" way?

Comment: Sorry - could you give an example of a constructor-ish class method? The table would have more than the domain column but I didn't think the additional columns added value to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about the rails way, so here it goes:

```
class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true

  def domain
    ActionDispatch::Http::URL.extract_domain(self.name)
  end
end

Host.find_by_name('www.abc.de').domain # => abc.de
```

Comment: Thanks - seems like I would still need to do: `Host.new(:name => 'www.abc.de').domain` if I was just using the class as a utility right?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about... What do you mean by "Utility Class"? If you just have a method to return the domain part of a host then use a helper or module or whatever!